# wp_get_recent_posts not working correctly with appended posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to append some posts to the wp_get_recent_posts function, so they are always retrieved with the normal results, the problem is that I dont get the posts I want to append in the results, am I doing something wrong?

```
$include = array(1, 2);

$args = array(
        'showposts' => 10, 
        'tag_id' => '123',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'exclude' => $current_id,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'append' => $include,
    );

    $entries = wp_get_recent_posts($args, 'ARRAY_A');
```

If I remove the tag_id argument then the posts I want to append are included in the results but I need to filter the normal results by tag ID, seems that WP also filters the appended posts with the other arguments, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts there is no 'append' parameter, but there is an 'include' parameter that does what you want.

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'showposts' => 10, 
    'tag_id' => '123',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'exclude' => $current_id,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'include' => $include,
);
```